# Adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread

Tags: multithreading, android-fragments, android-filterable

**I've an Activity with a EditText (named "filtro") and a ListView (named "list_view"). When the user inserts text, the adapter should be refresh; if i change text many times, comes a crash followed by the message "Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread"

> AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes. [in ListView(2131689687, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class com.example.search.GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter)]

My code is:

```
searchedititext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (arg0.toString().length() > 1 ||!arg0.toString().isEmpty()) {
            dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(arg0.toString());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // cancel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // cancel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        if (searchedititext.getText().toString().trim().length() > 1) {
            cancel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            gif1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            setarrybg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            //new SendsearchAsyncTaskbefore().execute();
            gif1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            listView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            cancel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            setarrybg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            callflipanimation();
            searchresult.setText("");
        }
       // Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"vvvvvvv"+"\n"+arg0+"\n",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: So... what is your question?

Comment: i have a edittext and listview when enter the text in edittext it will call the server and get related data and disply in listview this is working fine but some time trough error

Comment: Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes    so i want to create the thread in adaptor class how to create i dont know please help me..

Comment: Changed the title and added a description about the issue (). Added the code from the link.